# $\infty$-norm of diagonalizable matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Let the matrix $A$ have distinct eigenvalues. Then we know that matrix is diagonalizable and the eigenvector forms a basis and $A = V D V^{-1}$, where columns of $V$ are eigenvector of $A$. If we do the Gram-Schmidt process on the basis we can get an orthonormal basis and also the columns of $V$ can be changed to that. Then if we take infinite norm of the matrix $A$, it is same as largest absolute eigenvalue of $A$. Is my reasoning correct?

By infinite norm, I mean

$$\| A \|_{\infty} := \max_{i}\sum_{j}\vert a_{ij}\vert$$

Is the statement "the infinite norm of the diagonalizable matrix $A$ is the same as largest absolute eigenvalue of $A$" correct?

Comment: First of all, it's not clear what you mean by the "infinite norm" of a matrix

Comment: Second, no, your reasoning is not correct. Applying the Gram Schmidt process to a set of eigenvalues does not necessarily give you a basis of eigenvalues.

Comment: I think infinite norm is supposed to be infinity norm (i.e. $\Vert A\Vert_\infty$)?

Comment: I have updated the definition of norm. Original question reduced to $\parallel V \parallel_{\infty}\parallel V^{-1}\parallel_{\infty} =1$, where the columns of $V$ are eigenvector of $A$.

Comment: I have checked it numerically, statement is not true.